# What's the purpose of libgit2-backend?

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to build a website that supports git version control. I'm using libgit2 for the backend. But I think filesystem is not so easy to scale and to guarantee data integrity. I noticed that libgit2 has custom backend (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2-backends) support where I can use a database for some storage.

Initially I hoped that I can completely get rid of filesystem by saving everything git related into a database. But after I tried the sqlite backend, It seems that libgit2 still need to generate a .git folder on my filesystem? Can I remove the .git folder when I use a database as the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few "limitations" to having a working, "in-memory" repository using libgit2, even though there's support for "some" in-memory-ness. As you found out, there are API endpoints for both custom object databases (`.git/objects/`) and the refdb (`.git/refs/`), and the config subsystem can work in-memory. But that is not the case for all other things that can go in `.git/`, because there's no customization point at the repo-level — and IMHO this is not git we're talking about anymore when you're completely fs-less — work isn't really going in this direction.

- Feature-request: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/4671
- Discussion on a fix + some branches with "preparatory design work": https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/4967

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think I should stop spending time on this direction and focus on scaling the filesystem? Do you have insights on how github/gitlab handles this? Do they rely on cloud filesystems like glusterfs?

Comment: what I hope to have is an abstraction for fs in libgit2 (instead of a few backends that only partially allow me do in-mem). libgit2 can still function the same, interacting with the "fs". I can implement my in mem fs apis and in the end of git operations, I get a blob representing the entire repo. And I can save the blob into a database.

Comment: I have no idea what GitHub does with libgit2, but I'd be surprised they'd carry much upstreamable code around, so it's more likely akin to what I described : a custom refdb + odb backed by a database, and normal filesystem to `.git` for the rest of the stuff, most likely because they need still need `git` to do some tasks (eg. libgit2 doesn't do "git-gc").